# Can't resolve to plugin published in Bintray

Tags: sbt

I followed the instructions described in the [sbt manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Bintray+For+Plugins) to publish an sbt plugin to Bintray, using the `bintray-sbt` plugin. It got published ok, but I'm having problems resolving to it.

I have this in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("alpeb", "sbt-plugins")

addSbtPlugin("com.alpeb" % "sbt-gitignore" % "1.0.1")
```

When I start `sbt` for any given project, it tries to resolve the plugin to something like
  https://dl.bintray.com/alpeb/sbt-plugins/com/alpeb/sbt-gitignore_2.10_0.13/1.0.1/sbt-gitignore-1.0.1.pom

but Bintray put my files under
 https://dl.bintray.com/alpeb/sbt-plugins/com.alpeb/sbt-gitignore/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/
and it seems there are no poms under there, just xml and jars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like there's a problem with

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("alpeb", "sbt-plugins")
```

Using this instead did the trick:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "bintray-alpeb-sbt-plugins",
  url("http://dl.bintray.com/alpeb/sbt-plugins"))(
  Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Your plugin is published using ivy pattern, but `Resolver.bintrayRepo()` is a shortcut for a maven repo pattern (which is the default). Not sure why your plugin was published that way...

Comment: @JBaruch publishing with ivy style pattern is recommended in sbt best practices: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html

Comment: Also `resolvers += Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo("alpeb", "sbt-plugins")` will work.

Answer (score 1):

The sbt's [Bintray-For-Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html) manual also tells to link your plugin to sbt's shared repository which probably may do the trick. But I solved the same issue with `Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo` which is essentially the same as @AlejandroPedraza suggested:

`resolvers += Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo("alpeb", "sbt-plugins")`